Establishing MX record priorities to achieve email provider failover
I have a question regarding an MX record failover scenario that I'm hoping someone can help answer. Assuming a single domain has established tenants with both Microsoft Office 365 and Google Workspace, would it be possible to create multiple MX records that prioritizes one service and; should that higher MX priority service go offline temporarily, the lower priority email service's MX record would take over?
So say a business primarily uses Office 365, and they have their priority "0" MX record pointed to Office 365. But they also have a priority "1" MX record pointed to Google Workspace. If Office 365 experiences an outage, would emails begin to send to the established mailboxes at Google Workspace instead? And once Office 365 recovers, emails would automatically return to sending to the Office 365 mailboxes?
Thank you for the clarification!

Yes, it must be like this, but no guarantees. The selection of the MX is given to the discretion of the client, which is the originating or relaying server in this case. If it conforms to to the spec, it will work like you described. If it doesn't, it won't.
Know anyone who doesn't? I can suggest: spam bots. They just attempt to send spam to all the endpoints they see, no matter what priority is there.
I strongly suggest to set up your backup MX to just collect all the received mail and always relay all the collected mail to the main once it's up, possibly, with ETRN service (the special technique in the SMTP protocol for the server to request the mail destined for it, to quickly trigger the relaying). I don't have any idea of how to set up Google Workspace this way, or even whether it is possible to do so.
If you don't do this, your setup would be quite frustrating to users. They will be needed to always consult both unconnected receiving systems, because they wouldn't have a clue which one actually received the particular mail they're expecting. Administrators also wouldn't be too happy, as they will be in the need to manage two sets of users and other mail addresses, like aliases, and keep them always in sync; that's error prone. Any problems, like missing or undelivered mail, will be ten times harder to investigate (as if it was too easy in the first place). Overall, if you aren't able to setup relaying or some other means of synchronization, better only use one coherent system and concentrate on making it robust instead of inventing such murky schemes.

Great answer - Thanks, Nikita!
